# SQL Command "Timeout expired" Exception while handling ClientInsertServerInsert sync conflict

Tags: sql, vb.net, synchronization, sql-server-ce

I am working with synchronizing 2 databases (SQL Express and SQL Compact Edition) using VS 2010. It works fine when the program first running. However the SQL Command "Timeout expired" Exception occurred when the code has been executed for several times. The error message is:

Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.

The following is my code to handle [ClientInsertServerInsert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.synchronization.data.conflicttype.aspx) conflict. (Edit: According to this MSDN article this is to do with the client and server both inserting a row that have the same primary key value. This causes a primary key violation.)

```
    Dim conflictTableName As String = e.TableMetadata.TableName.ToString
    Dim serverConflictDT, clientConflictDT As DataTable
    Dim clientConflictID As Int16
    Dim new_ID As Int16
    Dim SqlCon As New SqlConnection
    clientConflictDT = e.Conflict.ClientChange
    serverConflictDT = e.Conflict.ServerChange

    If e.Conflict.ConflictType = ConflictType.ClientInsertServerInsert Then
        SqlCon = New SqlConnection(STR_SQL_CON)

        Using SqlCon
            If SqlCon.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then SqlCon.Open()
            MsgBox(SqlCon.PacketSize.ToString & vbNewLine & conflictTableName.ToString)
            Dim sqlStr = "SELECT CASE WHEN MAX(ID) IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE MAX(ID)+1 END               FROM " & conflictTableName

            Dim sqlcmd As New SqlCommand(sqlStr, SqlCon)
            sqlcmd.CommandTimeout = 2

            new_ID = sqlcmd.ExecuteScalar  '<- This is the line where the Exception occurred

            clientConflictID = clientConflictDT.Rows(0)(0)

            MsgBox(new_ID.ToString & conflictTableName.ToString)

            Try
                Using SqlCeCon As New SqlCeConnection(STR_SQLCE_CON)
                    If SqlCeCon.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then SqlCeCon.Open()

                    Dim sqlCeCmd As New SqlCeCommand
                    Dim sqlCeStr = Nothing

                    sqlCeStr = "SELECT CASE WHEN MAX(ID) IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE MAX(ID)+1 END FROM " & conflictTableName
                    sqlCeCmd = New SqlCeCommand(sqlCeStr, SqlCeCon)
                    If new_ID < sqlCeCmd.ExecuteScalar Then
                        new_ID = sqlCeCmd.ExecuteScalar
                    End If

                    sqlCeStr = "UPDATE " & conflictTableName & " SET id=" & new_ID & " WHERE id=" & clientConflictID
                    sqlCeCmd.CommandText = sqlCeStr
                    sqlCeCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                End Using
            Catch ex As Exception

            Finally

            End Try

        End Using


    End If
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Increase the commandtimeout property value.

Comment: I tried to change the timeout value to 0, yet it still doesn't move on

Comment: are you using link server for sql compact edition. share the connection string used to connect both sql server. On which line of code you are getting issue. Modifiy the commandtimeout for sql compact edition command.

Comment: sqlprofiler to trace what values cause the problem? is it causing a primary key violation or are the commands timing out?

Answer (score 2):

I suppose it was caused by the database lock. After I modify the SQL SELECT statement from

```
"SELECT CASE WHEN MAX(ID) IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE MAX(ID)+1 END FROM " & conflictTableName
```

to

```
"SELECT CASE WHEN MAX(ID) IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE MAX(ID)+1 END FROM " & conflictTableName & " WITH (NOLOCK)"
```

then the problem solved.

Anyway, thanks for all the comments :-)